# Render all the components in the same place in using Router and Links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a sidebar and a TopNav that I render inside App component.

My hierarchy is like

`Index > App > SideBar [> Lnks] = TopNav [> Links]  = Content`

I mean to say My `App` is rendered inside `Index`. Inside `App`, there are 3 Components named **Topnav, SideNav, Content** .
I want `Topnav ,Sidenav` to be available everytime but the linkes given in these navs should be rendered inside the `Content`. How am I supposed like this?

Below is my App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SideNav /> //SideNav should be rendered always
                <TopNav />  //This one too 
                <div className={'content'}>
                    Render All the data from the links in Sidenav and Topnav here.
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and my index.js looks like the code below

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here's the  [exact demo](https://www.kirupa.com/react/examples/react_router_final.htm) of what I want to do.

**I just want to know the `Routing` configuration. What and where to put routing configurations**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This app.js work

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import SideNav from './Components/SideNav';
import TopNav from './Components/TopNav';
import Home from './Components/Home';
import Stuff from './Components/Stuff';
import Noroute from './Components/Noroute';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SideNav/>
      <TopNav/>
      <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route path='/stuff' component={Stuff} />
          <Route  component={Noroute} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and create folder Components and add your components

SideNav.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
class SideNav extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li><Link to={'/'} className="nav-link"> Home </Link></li>
                    <li><Link to={'/stuff'} className="nav-link">Stuffs</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SideNav;
```

Comment: What if I want to pass the props to the children? How would I do that?

Comment: Lets say if you want to pass some data from App.js to SideNav then 
<SideNav value1="1"/> and in the SideNav you can get inside render function using "this.props.value"

Comment: No. Not in the App. But the components rendered using the Router Link.

Comment: ``` component={Stuff} ``` . What if I want to pass the values. Do I have to pass the props in the ```App``` or in the ```SideNav``` given ```SideNav``` contains link to the ```Stuff```

Comment: Values cannot be pass  in Router section. Pass data from parent to child will get work when we directly call component like we did for SideNav or TopNav